# Using **kwargs, a dictionary from views was not successfully pass to a function in models properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass a dictionary in views to a function in models and using **kwargs to further manipulate what i want to do inside the function. I try to call the dict before passing it in to the function. The data is there. The moment the dict was pass to the function (isAvailable) the kwargs is empty.

Here are the code snippets from views.py.

```
def bookingAvailable(request):
    available = isAvailable(data=request.data)
```

Here are the code snippets from models.py

```
def isAvailable(**kwargs):
    bookedDate = kwargs.get('bookedDate')
    customerID = kwargs.get('customerID')
    cpID = kwargs.get('cpID')
```

request.data is populated with data in a dictionary form. But the moment it got in to **kwargs everything is gone. Not so sure what happen in between. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at `kwargs["data"]` in `isAvailable()`. `**kwargs` gives you _keyword_ arguments. You get a dict whose keys are the names of the arguments passed in.

Comment: `isAvailable(**request.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `isAvailable(data=request.data)`, `kwargs` will be assigned a dictionary that looks like

```
{
    "data": ...
}
```

Notice there is no key `"bookedDate"` or `"customerID"` because you explictly specified `data=...` in the call.

I assume that `bookedData` and `customerID` are keys in `request.data`. To pass these keys as key word arguments, use the `**` operator:

```
isAvailable(**request.data)
```

In addition to this change, you can declare the parameters explicitly:

```
def isAvaialble(bookedDate, customerId, cpId):
    pass
```

Notice how much less code this is than calling `kwargs.get()` for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should get first data dictionary from kwargs and then get fields from data dictionary:

```
def isAvailable(**kwargs):
  data = kwargs.get('data')
  bookedDate = data.get('bookedDate')
  customerID = data.get('customerID')
  cpID = data.get('cpID')
```

Comment: It'd probably be cleaner and make more sense to just unpack it at the call site instead of introducing an additional nesting of the keyword argument dictionary under the `"data"` key